# Filtering a column based on a list of variables

Tags: r

How can I filter everything that is in ".new_england"?

table is called popdata

| state | type | pop |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alabama | One | 1 |
| Alabama | Two | 2 |
| Alabama | Three | 3 |

for context:

```
.new_england = ("CT" "MA" "ME" "NH" "RI" "VT")

y <- state.name[match(c(.new_england),state.abb)]
```

for context:

```
y = ("Connecticut" "Massachusetts" "Maine" "New Hampshire" "Rhode Island" "Vermont")

data_ne <- (filter(popdata, popdata$state == y))
```

Its only return some rows, skipping states or rows for states. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Can you edit to fix the errors in the code? For example `.new_england = c("CT", "MA", "ME", "NH", "RI", "VT")`. And you don't need `$` inside `filter()`, just the column name `state` will do. Aside from that you probably want to use `%in%` instead of `==`.

Comment: Thank you. Changing == to %in% worked. Will need to go back and learn the differences, etc. Much appreciated @neilfws